# wpf xaml to c# TargetProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to convert xaml code to c#
I have two animation xaml code,
first fade in animation :
in xaml :

> Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"

in c# : `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));`

second moving animation
in xaml :

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
```

How to convert that second xaml code to c# TargetProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to create that PropertyPath:

```
var path1 = new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[3].Y");
var path2 = new PropertyPath("(0).(1)[3].(2)", UIElement.RenderTransformProperty, 
                                               TransformGroup.ChildrenProperty,
                                               TranslateTransform.YProperty);
```

Comment: thx for your solution :) but i still confuse why myRectangle not animate